# Visual C++ reports an ambiguous symbol error for non-ambiguous class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following C++ code,

```
namespace {
  class ExprParentFinder {
    friend class CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer;
  };
}

class CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer {
public:
  CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer() {}
};

int main() {
  CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer TypeAnalyzer;
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine with Clang/GCC. However, MSVC chokes, and reports

> 1>  ConsoleApplication2.cpp
>
> 1> consoleapplication2.cpp(29): error C2872: 'CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer': ambiguous symbol
>
> 1>  consoleapplication2.cpp(23): note: could be 'CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer'
>
> 1>  consoleapplication2.cpp(19): note: or '`anonymous-namespace'::CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer'

Is `CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer TypeAnalyzer` really ambiguous here from a C++ standards point of view, or is this an MSVC bug. If so, what's causing this error.

The work around is to change the code to

```
int main() {
  ::CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer TypeAnalyzer;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the `CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer` class ever forward-declared?

Comment: This is a minimum reproducible example - this code file is the only thing you need to demonstrate the ambiguity.

Comment: How does the `ExprParentFinder` know about the existence of `CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer` if it's not declared?

Comment: From friend class CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know that classes could be forward declared in friend declarations ... interesting to know though!

Comment: What happens if you just change `friend class CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer;` to `friend class ::CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer;`  ?

Comment: http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual

Comment: Another work-arround is to forward-declare the class before the namespace. I suppose that the `friend` specification forward-declares the class in the actual namespace, if it is not known yet (howewer, currently I don't know whether or not it is C++ standard conformant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is well-formed (i.e., MSVC bug) but unlikely to be what you actually want. [[namespace.memdef]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.memdef#3), footnote omitted:

> If a `friend` declaration in a non-local class first declares a class,
>   function, class template or function template the friend is a member
>   of the innermost enclosing namespace. The `friend` declaration does
>   not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup
>   ([basic.lookup.unqual]) or qualified lookup ([basic.lookup.qual]).

`friend class CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer;` declares `CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer` to be a member of the unnamed namespace, but that name is not visible to name lookup.

Then, `class CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer { /* ... */ };` declares (and defines) a *different* class also called `CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer` as a 
member of the global namespace; this class is not a friend of `ExprParentFinder`.

Because the unnamed namespace's `CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer` isn't visible to name lookup, the only `CodeCompletionTypeContextAnalyzer` that can be found is the second one, and there is no ambiguity.